# Did Darth Sidious have a contingency plan in case Anakin didn't turn to the Dark Side?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

Did Darth Sidious have a contingency plan if Anakin decided not to turn to the Dark Side of the Force? If so, what was it?

Comment: I thought "What if" questions were clearly off topic ?

Comment: @Kalissar - true "what of" are. This is a real question merely being mis-labeled as "what if"

Comment: I think this is still unanswerable - unless some author has written an alternate timeline

Comment: Perhaps training jarjar in the ways of the dark side?

Comment: @Richard The galaxy surely would have immediately surrendered, just to get him to go away.

Comment: @Xantec - Having Senator Binks hanging around for 20 years certainly explains why the Emperor was so pleased to have disbanded the Senate...

Comment: According to the Legends EU, Palpatine had multiple contingency plans in place. These included multiple potential apprentices, and even a project to resurrect the dead Maul.

Comment: Not many people know this but pretty much all the events of the Star Wars movies are caused by Jar Jar. The clumsy Gungan was actually possessed by Darth Plagueis' spirit the entire time and set out to destroy his traitorous apprentice by aiding the Jedi and messing with the Senate by being the biggest dumbass in the republic's history. In fact he foresaw that Anakin would become Sidious' apprentice and made multiple attempts to kill him during the first movie, the most obvious one being dropping a wrench into his pod racer in the hope that it might explode during the race. ;)

Answer (score 17):

The [Book of Sith](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Book_of_Sith%3a_Secrets_from_the_Dark_Side_%28real-life_book%29) is an EU book that contains a detailed description of Palpatine's end goal in his own words: amassing absolute personal power and living forever as Emperor of the galaxy. Obviously, this ran counter to the Rule of Two, where each Sith Master is eventually killed and replaced by his apprentice. Palpatine thus abandoned it in favor of a [Rule of One](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_One_%28Palpatine%27s_Doctrine%29), which had him as immortal ruler, training others in the ways of the Dark Side not as apprentices to replace him but merely as agents to support him.

This means that Palpatine did not see Anakin has his apprentice, but merely as a tool to be used towards that goal - a powerful and useful tool, yes, but most certainly expendable! If you think about it, there is nothing Vader did that Palpatine couldn't have sent someone else to do or done himself.

So if Anakin had not turned, Palpatine would simple have killed him along with the other Jedi.

Comment: Supporting canon cites?

Comment: @DVK: Wookiepedia cites a canon source ("Book of Sith") re Palpatine's goals. The rest seems obvious - or can you give any reason why Anakin was not completely expendable to Palpatine?

Comment: The former (direct cite, NOT Wookiepedia link :) should be edited into the answer. As for the latter, that's speculation (regardless of how logical it is) and should also be explicitly highlighted as such. Otherwise, nobody can decide if your answer is just a random guess or correct.

Comment: This makes sense, but makes it odd that he would actively drive Anakin to kill Count Dooku. If other Sith were mere tools to Palpatine, it wouldn't make sense to sacrifice one to *maybe* gain another, especially when their areas of proficiency don't readily overlap.

Comment: This answer is reflected in the (extremely non-canon) ending to the video game "Star Wars Battlefront II" in Galactic Conquest mode, should the Separatists be victorious and conquer the galaxy. Darth Sidious is briefly shown killing Anakin with Force Lightning. This aligns with the general idea of Anakin being incidental to Sidious's ultimate plan, not a cornerstone in its conception. Anakin/Vader is definitely disposable, which is why Sidious so easily considers replacing Vader with Luke later.

Answer (score 3):

Anakin's turning to the dark side wasn't something that just suddenly happened; it was long prepared and by the time the crucial moment came, Palpatine would have been utterly confident of it.

The preparation obviously goes back as far as Episode 1, where we have the following quote from him:

> And you, young Skywalker. We will watch your career with great interest.

Through Episode 2 and 3 everything is a build up, until in Episode 3 we hear him say:

> Soon I will have a new apprentice, one far younger and more powerful.

It's not as if Anakin had any decision in this matter.  Palpatine had manipulated the situation all the way.

Comment: I dont think that Anakin really hit Palpatines radar until he thwarted Duuku's attempts on Amiedala.  That is backed up in the novel "Darth Plageious"

Comment: @Chad - a direct quote from Episode 1 (given above) says otherwise - Palpatine had his eye on Anakin from the outset.  I honestly think the movie trumps the EU in this regard (which is precisely why I confine evidence to the movies where possible).

Comment: That was a politician throwing out meaningless platitudes that had the irony of coincidence. Lucas loves that sort of play.

Comment: @Chad: or it was someone making an important statement in full knowledge, which only *appears* to be a meaningless platitude. It was knowable to Palpatine that Anakin had immense potential in the Force, and any such individual would indeed have been of great interest to him.

Comment: However, I disagree that Anakin had no choice. Palpatine is not omniscent, his manipulations not perfect (otherwise he would not have lost to Luke). In fact, the only way to *appear* to be omniscent is to have contingency plans for everything.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt - Palpatine never shows any of the ability to play the long game that Plagious does.  Palpatine is an opportunist who does not take risks where he is not the heavy favorite.  It was nothing more than a platitude that would not have even been note worthy except that we already knew how the prequels end and it was some delicious irony and foreshadowing.

Comment: @chad I disagree. Palpatine had been psychologically manipulating Anakin since he was a little boy because he knew from his midichlorian count that he would make an extremely powerful puppet. I think in the end Anakin didn't have a choice. Not because Sidious manipulated him through the force but because Anakin's evil was a seed that was planted and tended to by Palpatine for almost his entire life.

Comment: @MatthewStevenson - It is pretty obvious that you have not read the Legacy EU.  The technique used in the movies is called forshadowing and may have been intended to make the viewer wonder if it was a long con, but the books made it quite clear the emperor was not a long game player but rather one who was quite adept at picking opportunities to advance himself.  Even what appeared to be a brilliant plan by palpatine to land himself at the head of the republic was actually the work of his master plagieus.

Answer (score -4):

After Mace kills Sidious, Anakin loses faith in the Jedi, leaves the Order and the Republic ends it's alliance with the Jedi. Anakin then becomes the leader of the Republic Army, and fights in a war against the Jedi. The Jedi are completely wiped out, except for Obi-Wan and Yoda. From there, Anakin meets Sidious's spirit, and becomes his Apprentice, Darth Vader. Vader, under the instruction of Sidious, dissolves the Republic and reshapes it into the Empire. He rules as the 'Hero with no Fear' that the press and the citizens love, while Sidious manipulates him into doing as he says. After that, the events of the Original Trilogy play put as usual, except Tarkin has no power over Vader. Vader is basically a puppet ruler.

I can't imagine that dying was Sidious's plan, but if Anakin didn't turn in his office, Sidious would have been killed. So that would have been his backup plan in case he did.

Comment: Any canon to back that up?

Comment: Anakin didn't suddenly loose faith in the Jedi, he expressed doubts in their order consistently throughout the entire original trilogy.